Getting ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 error when sending a GET request from FlowXO to GLPI API
I’m trying to send a GET request to the GLPI API. When testing the request in Postman (URL: http://127.0.0.1/apirest.php/), everything works fine, and I get a 200 OK response. Other requests sent through Postman also work without any issues.

However, when I'm in editing mode in Constructor of Telegram bot using FlowXO and add an action ("Webhooks & HTTP") with the same request (http://127.0.0.1/apirest.php/), I encounter a problem. Here’s how I’ve set it up in FlowXO:
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1/apirest.php/
Method: GET
Headers: None
Format: JSON


When I save and launch the bot, the request fails with the error:
ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

The interaction history in FlowXO shows the type as "Is Progress" instead of "Error," which usually indicates a valid URL. Despite that, the request fails. This happens with other requests to the same API as well.
I suspect there might be an issue with how FlowXO is trying to access 127.0.0.1, but I’m unsure how to troubleshoot or fix it.
What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

"when I set up a Telegram bot using FlowXO"... set up how? Are by any chance using Docker or some other container orchestration?

@Phil, oh, sorry, I meant that I'm in editing mode on constructor which allows me to add different types of actions. I'm asking about webhooks here

@Phil, edited description, thanks. No, i don't use Docker here. I use webserver Apache, which's configured according to GLPI Installation Guide.
